# CALCULATE TOTAL NUMBER OF ESTIMATED HOURS

Tags: database-design

I had a question regarding a small task I've been assigned. Below I have pasted the question and a screenshot of the database layout. Now I just don't understand what exactly I'm meant to create, a user defined function maybe? But how?

Question: Calculate and return the total number of estimated hours involved in a given stage at the date of the estimate (i.e. before any further changes to estimated hours were made).

(Screenshot) - Table data from: CHARGE_GRADE, TASK_TYPE, TASK, CHARGE_GRADE, ASSIGNMENT, EMPLOYEE.

[image: screenshot]

[image]

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, which means that your post will likely be closed without an answer.  Please edit the question to provide more specifics on your task.  If the improvement is significant even a closed question will be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

When I look at the question, it is not important what you create to achieve the result: *calculate and return the total number of estimated hours involved in a given stage at the date of the estimate*.

I would advise though to just create a query to return the result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you kindly assist with the query for that. Thanks

Comment: Step 1: Determine the table you want to get the data from. Step 2: determine the function you need to summarize the data. Step 3: Select only the date of the estimate or group by the date to see all dates. That's all you are getting from me. You should do some thinking / searching yourself too :-).